# Data repeating instead of looping

Tags: java, loops

I am unable to loop through my time conversion data and display it for every column.

The output is supposed to display different time converted for each column, but instead it is displaying the same time for every column.

Here's my code:

```
  String MS = "";
  String time = MS;

        //Converting date and time to milliseconds

    for (int t = 0; t < timeMS.length; t ++)
        {
            String strDate = timeMS[t];
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            Date getDate = sdf.parse(strDate);
            getDate.getTime();
            MS = time + (getDate.getTime());
        }

        while ( rs.next() )
            {
                String data1 = rs.getString("data1");
                if ( !set1.contains( data1) )
                        set1.add(data1);                        

                 String set2 = "";
                   {
                     if ( rs.getString("data2") != null )
                     set2 = rs.getString("data2");

                     String[] set3 = set2.split("<SPLIT>");

                for ( int i = 0 ; i <set3.length ; i ++ )
                    if ( dataGroup2.containsKey(set3 [i]) )
                        dataGroup2.get(set3 [i]).put(data1, MS);
                     }
            }   

            for ( int i = 0 ; i < set1.size(); i++)
            {
                stringWriter.append( set1.get(i)  + ",");

                for ( String set3 : dataGroup2.keySet() )
                {
                    if ( dataGroup2.get(set3 ).containsKey(  set1.get(i)  ) )
                        dataGroup1.get(set3 ).append(MS +",");
                    else
                        dataGroup1.get(set3 ).append("0,");
                }
            }
```

**Current output**

```
    tyu,ghj,bnm
qwe,123, 0,  0,
asd, 0, 123, 0,
zxc, 0,  0, 123,
```

**Desired output**

```
    tyu,ghj,bnm
qwe,123, 0,  0,
asd, 0, 456, 0,
zxc, 0,  0, 789,
```

Comment: please format your code, properly to as to ease reading

Comment: What is `set1`? you have lines `String set2 = "";` then how can you have `String[] set3 = set2;` I leave aside the programming logic, Is this code runnable?

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala just formatted it, hope its clear enough.

Comment: @Blip this is just a snippet of my codes and as far as things go, yes, it can be run.

Comment: could you tell me `String set2 = "";` and `String[] set3 = set2;` work? Also you have not give the line where you have declared `set1`.

Comment: @Blip yes it works. set1 is declared a few lines before all these codes.

Comment: Post how it is declared.

Comment: @Blip `List<String> set1 = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: Ok, now could you tell me how `String set2 = "";` and `String[] set3 = set2;` work? As you are assigning a `String` to a `String` array?

Comment: @Blip `String[] set3 = set2;.split("<SPLIT>");` set3 is supposed to be like this, forgot to type in. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: could you please correct to code and post a proper code to understand the program logic. Also I noted a starting `{` after `String set2 = "";` could you explain its use.

Comment: @Blip its pretty redundant I guess, all these codes are passed to me from someone for me to continue. The logic of these codes is to extract data from database and output it into .CSV format. It will be quite inconvenient to post more codes as I would have to change variable name because the actual name is kind of private for this project.

Comment: Ok I understand that but You should place the complete workable logic. Your question itself leaves many unanswered questions. Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for proper help.

Comment: @Blip alright. The codes I posted is just a short snippet of my codes. I posted this set of codes as the error lines within this short paragraph of codes.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared MS outside the loops. And at the end of the first for loop you will have just 1 value for it. The time variable refers to the "" string.
So for each iteration MS becomes: "" + "formatedTime(timeMS[t])". And you are left with the formated time for only the last item in timeMS (i.e. 123).

In the while loop you use MS but it only has the one value left from the for loop (123). 
Either use array of strings for MS or rearrange your code in the first for loop.

Comment: could you tell me `String set2 = "";` and `String[] set3 = set2;` work?

Comment: Hi, mind elaborating on rearranging my codes in the first for loop?

Comment: @Blip They are incompatible types. Don't know what rs.getString("data2") assigns to set2 tho.

Comment: @Justalazyguy The choice is yours. My first suggestion is for you to try putting the next 2 loops inside the first for loop. That means moving the } that comes before the while at the end of the code snippet you shared.

Comment: @LaurentiuL. its not working still, thanks for the help though :)

Comment: @justalazyguy Do write your MS value to a logger's output or the system standard output stream and post it here. You can insert it right before MS usage -  dataGroup2.get(set3 [i]).put(data1, MS);    or 
dataGroup1.get(set3 ).append(MS +",");

Comment: @LaurentiuL. This might be abit burdensome but i'm not sure how to do what you just said as i'm quite new to all these. The most in-depth I've learned was array.

Comment: @justalazyguy System.out.println("Ms value : "+ MS); anywhere after the first for loop. Then you will start getting a clearer picture. But the way to learn the flow is to debug the app, and put some breakpoints using some IDE.

Comment: @LaurentiuL. Ms value : 1429070100000
Thanks for the tip! I've notice that if I remove the while loop, the MS value will be different but the columns would duplicate base on the no. of rows in my database.

Comment: @justalazyguy You have a way to go before understanding it all. First in order for this value to be relevant you need to show the input data. Then you need to mark the line where you inserted the println. But that is beyond the scope of this question. My suggestion of printing MS's value was meant to guide you on the right path of understanding why you only have 1 value. Now you are free to debug / print all the variables in your code in order to understand how each section works and what basically what happens in every point.